# How to update React state from iframe

Tags: reactjs

I have a React page:

```
export default () => {
  const [thing, setThing] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Here is your selected thing:</p>
      {thing}
      <iframe src="localhost:8000" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The iframe is a plain html file.
What is the best way to pass the `setThing` handler to the iframe?

### Note

I have edit access to the plain html file. So, I'm able to edit it or add the handler there if needed.

### My attempt:

I tried accessing it using a React ref like this:

```
iframeRef.current.contentWindow.document.getElementById('addThingButton').addEventListener('click',(newThing) => setThing(newThing))
```

But this gave me this error in the browser's terminal:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
```

I feel like this is too hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why to have iframe, why not iframe as react component?

Comment: It's a limitation of the project I'm working on. The iframe must be rendered on a different server.

Comment: I also have edit access to the code of the iframe. Might that help @r_batra

Comment: The html page is hosted on port 8000 but what is the port of your react app?

Comment: React is hosted on port 3000 @whygee

Comment: That's probably the cause since localhost:3000 and localhost:8000 aren't the same origin anything you try to do in the iframe is blocked. You would need to setup a proxy between port 3000 and 8000 or configure the server that is hosting the html file to accept cross-origin handling.

Comment: But in production, they will be entirely different domains, not just ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably `post` a message from iframe and listen to that message in your react component. Once you receive that message from iframe, you can trigger the state update.

```
export default () => {
  const [thing, setThing] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
       // identify correctness of message from iframe
       if(event.data === '<YourMessageToParentWindow>') {
         setThing(newThing);
       }
     }

  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Here is your selected thing:</p>
      {thing}
      <iframe src="localhost:8000" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In your iframe code, you need to add logic to `postMessage` to the parent window, which I am assuming is on a button click from the question above:

```
<button onclick="window.parent.postMessage('<YourMessageToParentWindow>')"> SomeRandomText </button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. I should also note, it's best you check the event.origin domain as well. You don't want other 3rd party domains to pass messages to the parent window.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, especially when you've multiple iframes / integrations in your app.